# NodeJS dynamically environment variable setup

Tags: javascript, node.js

I create a NodeJS server and trying to setup environment variables dynamically. But I'm facing a weird problem. I create a `env.js` file and here is the related code:

```js
const environment = {}

environment.dev = {
  port: 3000,
  envName: 'dev'
}

environment.prod = {
  port: 5000,
  envName: 'prod'
}

const currentEnvironment = typeof process.env.NODE_ENV === 'string'
  ? process.env.NODE_ENV
  : 'dev'

console.log('current environment: ', currentEnvironment) // get currentEnvironment: prod
console.log('environment obj: ', environment) // get environment obj correctly
console.log('getting obj from environment obj: ', environment[currentEnvironment]) // But get undefined

const environmentToExport = typeof environment[currentEnvironment] === 'object'
  ? environment[currentEnvironment]
  : environment.dev

module.exports = environmentToExport
```

I can't figure out why I'm getting `undefined` in `environment[currentEnvironment]`.

And here is the `package.json` scripts from where I'm passing environment variable. I'm using `windows` by the way.

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "SET NODE_ENV=dev & nodemon index",
  "prod": "SET NODE_ENV=prod & nodemon index"
}
```

Note: I'm using exported `port` number while creating server. But incase of getting `undefined`, I'm always exporting `dev` environment ! Hope you understand my problem.

Comment: there should be double `&` sign `"SET NODE_ENV=dev && nodemon index"` 
And if you are not certain about server, you can use `cross-env` package

Comment: Try redefining your npm script as  `"prod": "SET NODE_ENV=prod& nodemon index"` _(Note the space has been removed between `prod` and the `&` character)_. Also do the same for your `dev` script, e.g. `"dev": "SET NODE_ENV=dev& nodemon index",`

Comment: @Girish single or double `&`, both works.

Comment: @RobC problem isn't in my scripts, I'm getting `NODE_ENV` value correctly.

Comment: @Robin - I'm fairly certain that the problem is in your npm script. Try adding the following; `console.log('current environment number of characters: ', currentEnvironment.length)` to your _node.js_ script just above your other `console.log` statements. Then run `npm run prod` via your CLI using your code as-is. It probably prints `5`, i.e. there is a space character at the end of `prod `. However, if you next change your npm script to `"prod": "SET NODE_ENV=prod& nodemon index"` (as per my previous comment) then `npm run prod` again it should print the correct number of characters, i.e. `4`.

Comment: Or, alternatively leave your npm-scripts as-is and on line no. 14 of your node.js script change `? process.env.NODE_ENV` to `? process.env.NODE_ENV.trim()` instead, i.e. use [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) to remove the trailing space character.

Comment: @RobC you are right, now problem is fixed by using `trim()` function. Although writing script like this  `"prod": "SET NODE_ENV=prod& nodemon index"`  doesn't solve my problem. Thanks.